# Last element value appears in first and last position when printing linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

Happy New Year.

This question arises from a project to program a game called Laby-chiffres in C. To see the game look in the third batch of games on this link: http://www.rci-jeux.com/jeux/labychiffres/laby.swf .

**Context**:
I am using a linked list to store the path taken by a player through a grid of numbers. The player's aim is to find a path from the departure point to the arrival point, with a given length and given total of the numbers in the path. There is a switch statement for a menu and then one to accept the direction the player wants to move in. This works as I have code that shows that the 'passage' of the player to each number is recorded correctly

**Problem**:
When I try to print the path (which is a requirement of the assignment - and useful for the player to see) I print the path in the correct order, except that the last element, i.e. where the player most recently moved to, is shown at the start and the end of the list.

*Example*: Player makes moves through positions with values as follows. Starting with the departure point value 5 -> 8 -> 4-> 1. What is printed at each stage is:

```
5->
8->8->
4->8->4->
1->8->4->1->
```

**What I have tried** 
I have looked at several other linked list questions, but none I have seen have the same issue that I have.
I have tried changing lots of things, but to be honest now more experimentally than anything. For example, changing the `empiler` function to add elements at the wrong end prints the path in the wrong order (as expected) but still prints the most recently reached number twice, just both at the start of the path rather than one at the start and one at the end.

**Relevant functions**
The lecturer has said explicitly that the printing needs to reverse the order so these are the printing functions:

```
void affiche_chemin (PLATEAU jeu, PILE pile){ 
    afficher_pile_inverse(&jeu , jeu.chemin.P_sommet);
    printf("\n");
}

void afficher_pile_inverse(PLATEAU *P_jeu, ELEMENT *P_cur){    
    if(P_cur != NULL){
        afficher_pile_inverse(P_jeu,P_cur->P_suivant);
        printf("%d->",lire_valeur_a(P_jeu,&P_cur->valeur));
    }       
}
```

`lire_valeur_a` reads the value in the grid, which is part of the `PLATEAU` structure given below and read in from a text file. This appears to work so I am not including it to try to keep the question length down.

The function to add elements is :

```
ELEMENT* empiler(PILE *P_liste, ELEMENT *P_elt_ajoute){
   P_elt_ajoute ->P_suivant = P_liste->P_sommet; 
   P_liste->P_sommet = P_elt_ajoute;             
   return P_elt_ajoute;
}
```

Given the lecturers comments about needing to reverse the order to print correctly I think I am adding elements at the right end of the list.

These functions initialise the path, and allocate a new `ELEMENT`, and are just given for reference as used in the next extract.

```
void initialiser_pile(PILE *P_pile){
    P_pile->P_sommet = NULL;
}

ELEMENT *nouvel_element (POSITION nouvelle_valeur){
    ELEMENT *P_elt;
    P_elt =(ELEMENT*) malloc(sizeof(ELEMENT));
    if(P_elt ) {    /* NULL equivalent to false like 0 */
        P_elt->valeur = nouvelle_valeur;
        P_elt->P_suivant = NULL;
    }
    return P_elt;
}
```

This code sets up the path for the first time when the text file for the game is read, so it is the first time `empiler` is used to add an element to a path. (This extract is from a long function using `fscanf` multiple times to read the game text file, and seems to work correctly.)

```
ELEMENT *P_sommet = nouvel_element(PLAT->dep);
if (P_sommet == NULL){
    printf("Erreur d'allocation\n");
    return 0;
}
initialiser_pile(&PLAT->chemin);
empiler (&PLAT->chemin,P_sommet);
PLAT->longcur = 1;
PLAT->sumcur=PLAT->grille[PLAT->dep.indl][PLAT->dep.indc];
```

The following function is used for adding elements during the game.

```
int choix_indep_jeu_update(PLATEAU *jeu, POSITION *new_pos, int pas, int dir){  
    ELEMENT *new = nouvel_element(*new_pos);//1 Make new element

    if (new == NULL) return 0;
        empiler( &jeu->chemin, new );//should add new element

    jeu->longcur++;
    jeu->sumcur = jeu->sumcur + lire_valeur_a(jeu, new_pos);

    affiche_grille(*jeu);
    affiche_chemin(*jeu,jeu->chemin);
    return 1;
}
```

**Data Structures**
    typedef struct position_st{
        int indl;//indice of ligne
        int indc;//indice of colonne
        }POSITION;

```
typedef struct element_st{
    POSITION valeur;
    struct element_st *P_suivant;
    }ELEMENT;

typedef struct pile_st{
    ELEMENT * P_sommet;
    }PILE;

typedef struct plat_st{
//########## GAME FILE INFORMATION
    int nl;        //number of lines in grid
    int nc;        //number of columns in grid
    POSITION dep;  //position du depart: dep.indl and dep.indc
    POSITION arr;  //position d'arrive: arr.indl and arr.indc
    int longdem;   //length demanded
    int sumdem;    //total demanded
    int ** grille; //Playing grid 
//#######INFO re GAME IN PROGRESS ########
    int longcur;  //longueur courant
    int sumcur;   //totale courant
    PILE chemin;  //The path
    }PLATEAU;
```

Comment: This is a perfect opportunity to develop debugging skills.  Step through your code to see why it behaves the way it does.

Comment: You get an upvote anyway, since your question is infinitely better than most 'debug my code' questions, (which have 0 detail except for code with single-letter var names and the like).  Nevertheless, what @OliverCharlesworth says.  It's a lot of code, and you are in a better position to debug it than we are.  Get out that debugger and start breakpointing/stepping/inspecting.

Comment: OK, thanks Oliver and Martin. I will give that a go.

Comment: Because of the requirement to print the list of moves in reverse, perhaps it is worth mentioning that a simply created linked list (adding a new node at the root) will parse in reverse order anyway. And if you want to "undo" the most recent move, that is simple, because such a list can work like a LIFO stack. Also: why do you need `struct pile_st`? Can't you just use a pointer to `struct element_st` for the root of the linked list?

Comment: As a kind of cheap debugging, you could print the pointer value of the list node with `%p` in addition to the `valeur`. If all pointers are different (but your values aren't), then your `lire_valeur_a` has problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified your code and it seems to be working, assuming that you want empiler() to insert elements into the front of the list, so they end up in reverse order. I added afficher_pile_inverse1() so that the last value doesn't have a "->" after it. So the error is in creating the list or there's an issue with the grid function which you did not show.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int POSITION;

typedef struct element_st{
    POSITION valeur;
    struct element_st *P_suivant;
}ELEMENT;

typedef struct pile_st{
    ELEMENT * P_sommet;
}PILE;

void empiler(PILE *P_liste, ELEMENT *P_elt_ajoute){
   P_elt_ajoute ->P_suivant = P_liste->P_sommet; 
   P_liste->P_sommet = P_elt_ajoute;             
}

void afficher_pile_inverse1(ELEMENT *P_cur){    
    if(P_cur != NULL){
        afficher_pile_inverse1(P_cur->P_suivant);
        printf("%d->",P_cur->valeur);
    }       
}

void afficher_pile_inverse(ELEMENT *P_cur){    
    if(P_cur != NULL){
        afficher_pile_inverse1(P_cur->P_suivant);
        printf("%d",P_cur->valeur);
    }       
}

void affiche_chemin (PILE pile){
    afficher_pile_inverse(pile.P_sommet);
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void){
ELEMENT ae[4] = {{0,NULL},{1,NULL},{2,NULL},{3,NULL}};
PILE P_liste = {NULL};
size_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        empiler(&P_liste, &ae[i]);
    affiche_chemin(P_liste); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is not the order of printing but the fact that the last and first elements are given the same value when printing. The returned pointer to node is just a convenience; the function can safely be used in void context.

Comment: @MOehm -  I changed my example code so it's a simplified version of the code in the original post and it's working, so at least the problem is not in the functions included in my example code. The original poster hasn't responded, so I assume he's already fixed the problem.